# Estimating population increase

Tags: arcgis-10.5, population

How can I estimate the population in 2020 at a given area if you know that the current rate of increase is 1.25%/year?

What tools do I need to in a GIS Software to make the calculation?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  What GIS software are you using?  What have you tried?

Comment: You should point which GIS software you prefer/use, there are very different options, some with GUI and others which imply programming

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you this GRASS module https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/addons/r.futures.html
it is a tool specifically designed for population growth, where you can include constraints and your population projections (or rate of these), and other predictors which influence growth, such as roads or slope